# FreePBX: Basic config?

Tags: asterisk, sip, freepbx

I've just successfully set up an Asterisk+FreePBX install on an Amazon EC2 instance per this guide: http://voxilla.com/2009/10/15/voxillas-freepbx-in-a-cloud-step-by-step-1457 (I've also assigned it an Elastic IP).

I'd love to test it **without** buying any VoIP trunks yet. I understand that I can do that by just placing internal calls to two phones connected to the Asterisk server, right?

I'm using a softphone: CounterPath eyeBeam.

I can't seem to find any guide or resource online that will tell me what I need to do on the FreePBX side of things to set it up for just routing internal calls, nor what I need to enter in to CP's eyeBeam client (username, auth. name, password, etc.) in order to get it to connect to Asterisk.

Can somebody give me a quick primer? Or at least point me to an easily-digestible resource that could help me out?

EDIT: I did already find [this guide](http://nerdvittles.com/index.php?p=137), but it sets up the FreePBX to use outside VoIP trunks, which I don't want to purchase just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to just add two SIP extensions, Username, display name, password, apply changes, and in your eyeBeam add username, password and the IP address of your Asterisk as Domain (I don't have it installed, the domain part may be called differently).
Yes, it is that simple.

Comment: Great, that worked! The phones connect, but I have no audio... now what?

Comment: No audio on SIP is a fairly common problem, caused by NAT firewalls. Google "SIP no audio", or try http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/sip_nat_oneway_or_no_audio_asterisk.html