# FreePBX on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, iso, freepbx

I know I can install asterisk, freepbx on ec2 instance from the repository but for some reasons I was hoping to install the freepbx distro from an iso from my local machine to ec2 instance. Can anyone help with a way around it?

I want to install freepbx latest version on ec2 from an iso on my computer, it'd be a tremendous help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this.

In theory, you can install on a VM locally (to ESXi, Virtualbox, etc.) and then convert that into an EC2 ami, but that is a fairly convoluted process, and will end up being much more work than just sorting out how to install from the FreePBX repo.

Why do you not just want to use one of the FreePBX AMIs that are already available for EC2?

Comment: thanks very much for your comments, and about the ec2 freepbx ami, as long as I know I will to purchase this, instead I was hoping to use a free version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to [figure out](https://askubuntu.com/q/978361/45156) `docker`, and haven't gotten into `freepbx`, but it's [easy enough](https://hub.docker.com/r/jmar71n/freepbx/):

`docker run --net=host -d -t jmar71n/freepbx`

which I ran on a free Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance.  Unlikely to be useful for production, but it starts up fine.  Certainly not the first to do something [along these lines](https://serverfault.com/q/106179/132080).